# Resubscribe IObservable after merge

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an IObservable that is initially listening to one source:

```
_itemsChanged = Observable.Merge(item1.ObserveItemChanged);
_itemsChanged.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("item changed"));
```

As the app runs, additional items might be added and I want to merge the new item's stream to my existing one:

```
var item2 = new Item();
_itemsChanged.Merge(item2.ObserveItemChanged);
```

However, I only see output when item1 is changed.  Do I have to refresh the subscription somehow?  I expected the merged stream to be picked up right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to use a `Subject<IObservable<T>>` that you are subscribed to.  This lets you add more items on the fly.  Here is a way to abstract it a bit (the subject is a `Subject<Item>` which we then project and merge into the `Observable<T>`):

```
    var subject = new Subject<Item>();
    IObserver<Item> newItems = subject;
    IObservable<T> itemsChanged = subject.SelectMany(item => item.ObserveItemChanged);
    itemsChanged.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("change"));

    // add items
    newItems.OnNext(item1);
    newItems.OnNext(item2);
```